# backbone.js error when using fetch but not $.ajax()

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone.js-collections

I am having some trouble fetching a collection. I'm using the console's network inspector to see if I can figure out what's wrong and the only thing I see is the format of the Request Payload.

When making a `.fetch()` the Request Payload is being sent in this format:

```
query=this+is+my+query
```

This returns a 400 Bad Request status from my server. I have tested using:

```
$.ajax({
contentType: 'application/json',
async : false,
type:'POST',
url: '/search',
data: JSON.stringify({"query":"this is my query"}),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
    alert('yup');
},
error: function(data) {
    alert('nope');
}});
```

which returns my data as expected. In this case the Request Payload is in this format:

```
{"query":"enterprise search is gonna rock","scope":null}
```

I've tried passing in headers with my fetch:

```
my_results.fetch({data:{"query":"this is my query"}, type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json'});
```

Here is what my Model and Collection look like:

```
EnterpriseSearch.Result = Backbone.Model.extend(); 
EnterpriseSearch.Results = Backbone.Collection.extend({     
  model: EnterpriseSearch.Result,
  url: "/search"
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Excellent first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `data: JSON.stringify({"query":"this is my query"})` in your fetch options, just like you do when using `$.ajax`. jQuery will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for form data.